# Checkbox doen't display on-off values

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to create boolean field that displayed as checkbox:

```
function createBooleanField($name, $label, $bundle, $required=FALSE, $defaltVal=0){
    if(!isValidField($name)){
        return;
    }

    // Create the field base.
    $field = array(
        'field_name' => $name,
        'type' => 'list_boolean',
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    $instance = array(
        'field_name' => $name,
        'cardinality' => 1,
        'entity_type' => 'node',
        'type' => 'list_boolean',
        'label' => $label,
        'bundle' => $bundle,
        'required' => $required,
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'options_onoff',
            'settings' => array(
                'display_label' => true
            ),
        ),
        'settings' => array(
            'allowed_values' => array(
                '0' => 'No',
                '1' => 'Yes',
            ),
        ),
    );

    $instance['default_value'] = array(
        0 => array(
            'value' => $defaltVal,
        ),
    );

    field_create_instance($instance);
}
```

After I create a content type (of type $bundle) and display it in view in a table I see the values as 0-1 instead of 'Yes' - 'No'.

After I'm goign to  admin/structure/types/manage/MY_CONTENT_TYPE/fields/MY_BOOLEAN_FIELD
and insert it manualy :

[image]

Only there it works.
What I'm doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Why not use the standard built in Drupal boolean field?

Comment: Because it a module that creates content types programmatically

Comment: @NickF That's not a reason to avoid built in boolean fields... Probably you misunderstood something.

Comment: @Mołot I think you didn't understand the question. I'm just asking how create a boolean field programmatically and set "On value" and "Off value" through code. If it not possible I'd like to know. About avoiding manually, because the administrator shouldn't touch that field.